# How do I log SQL Statements in Dropwizard

Tags: java, sql, database, logging, dropwizard

How do I turn on SQL query logging for a Dropwizard application? I would like it to only log SQL in certain environments.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In your application YAML file add a "logging:" definition like the following:

```
# Logging settings.
logging:

  # The default level of all loggers. Can be OFF, ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG, TRACE, or ALL.
  level: INFO

   # Logger-specific levels.
   loggers:

      # Overrides the levels of certain packages or files.
      "org.skife.jdbi.v2": TRACE
```

Comment: This does not help. The SQL statement is logged but with parameters shown as simple '?' like:  "SELECT * FROM XY WHERE ID = ?"

Comment: If that is what you need @heaphach, hopefully you can use a debugger to figure out what parameters are being passed in. For the question I had above, this answer is sufficient and accurate, even if it does not solve your particular issue.

Comment: Yeah for me its clear what SQL is ued, but some managers want to log the exact SQL statement. However you are right, you answered the question above.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using jdbi?, if so, this is working for me:

Set a logger when you create the DBI instance:

```
DBI dbi = new DBI(dataSource);
dbi.setSQLLog(new SLF4JLog());
```

Add this configuration to your config file:

```
logging:
  level: INFO
  loggers:
    "org.skife": TRACE
```

I guess this idea should be also valid for Hibernate or any other DB access framework.

Answer (score 0):

Using jdbi 3, I had to configure the `Slf4JSqlLogger` like this:

```java
jdbi.setSqlLogger(new Slf4JSqlLogger());
```

... And set the log level of `org.jdbi.sql` to `TRACE` in my `config.yaml`:

```yaml
logging:
  level: INFO
  loggers:
    org.jdbi.sql: TRACE
```